# Is filtering on int better than filtering on date

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2017, query-performance

I have a system where most of our table has the current datetime as primary key and we filter most of the data based on the datetime.

The question, if I move this datetime to another new table and have an auto id in the new table. for eg.

```
Dates
id datetime
1  11/6/2019
2  11/7/2019
3  11/4/2019
4  11/8/2019
```

Now all the other tables will have id instead of datetime and filtering will be based on the id.

Will this improve performance or filter on a datetime is equal to filter on int?

I am using SQL Server 2017.

Comment: Date is 3 bytes where as INT is 4 bytes. There is [one case](http://www.made2mentor.com/2011/05/date-vs-integer-datatypes-as-primary-key-for-date-dimensions/) proving the date to be faster in 2008 but only slightly. Before you over optimize, how would you know which ID's to filter on? Date's seem more logical for a human to enter as a predicate than a correlating ID that I presume you'd have to look up first anyway. This could be something for you to test and post the results!

Comment: @scsimon - it is datetime not date, sorry I just edited the question.

Comment: I agree with @scsimon. We need to see the queries, in the end. I doubt that you will just replace an WHERE OrderDate > '20180324' with WHERE OrderID > 34729. I.e., there will probably be changes to the queries and those are more likely to affect performance.

Answer (score 1):

I would answer with: Keep it as it is with datetime!

One of the reasons is simple really, data type precedence. So, if you were ever to compare a `datetime` to an `integer`, the engine will decide that rather than converting `date`->`int` then compare `int = int`, it will convert `int`->`datetime` and compare `datetime = datetime`. Which stands the same for every single data type (like `varchar`)  except for:

1. user-defined data types
2. sql_variant
3. xml

in that order of precedence.

Date comparison functions are also optimized to a crazy degree and they run blitzing fast, so you won't be gaining much in terms of performance, in fact you might end up losing performance since you have to do a `join` operation and then (again) do a `where`(how else would you filter by dates after all, generated ID != date you're comparing with).

So you need to ask yourself, is it really necessary to move date into a separate table? If you're planning on having a Data Warehouse, it might help with making the TimeDim table but other than that I see no reason to do so.

If you are interested in data precedence, you can see the list here (highest to lowest, top to bottom): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017